# Generate the package.xml using a local project

Tags: salesforcedx, metadata-api, package.xml

I am trying to find a way to generate the package.xml using metadata stored locally on my machine without using any org.

I have found a lot of alternatives when you want to generate a package.xml using as a reference a defined environment but no result when you already have the metadata folder.

Do you know if it is possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `sfdx convert` commands as follows.

Let's say your metadata API files are stored in a folder called `mdapi`.

In folder `mdapi`, add a `package.xml` file with one metadata type found in your files for e.g ApexClass. The `package.xml` is required for convert command and must exist in the folder even if it does not list all components:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>ApexClass</name>  
  </types>
  <version>47.0</version>
</Package>
```

Convert `mdapi` folder to source format:

```
sfdx force:mdapi:convert -r ./mdapi/ -d force-app
```

Then convert the newly created `force-app` source format repository again to metadata API to generate the `package.xml` based on the files found

```
sfdx force:source:convert -r ./force-app/ -d mdapi2
```

The `mdapi2` folder will contain the `package.xml` file and the subfolders with the metadata components

Comment: I have tried to convert mdapi folder to source format without providing the package.xml inside the mdapi folder and I have received this error message "  the path specified is not a directory or doesn’t contain a package.xml"

Comment: I have edited my answer: in mdapi folder you need to specify a 'package.xml' file with one metadata type at least. This is required for the first sfdx convert command